# Add items to a collection from the item or from the collection?

Tags: lists, selection

I am building a song & playlist manager. Where should I put my join interface, in the song view or in the playlist view?

Is it better to:

1. enter a song's detail view
2. select "add this song to a playlist"
3. select a playlist to add it to

Or:

1. enter a playlist's detail view
2. select "add a song to this playlist"
3. select a song to add.

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about a spotify type app then the usual pattern would be option A. This is used for services like spotify and works quite well. Consider that step 1: "Enter a songs detail view" should probably be accessible without playing the song. On desktop the usual pattern is drag and drop.On mobile a more menu -> "⠇"/"⠂⠂⠂"option in the list can be used to access "add to playlist" option.

Option B is not an established pattern and it would be harder to implement as the selection part is not straightforward. Unless we are talking about files, in which case I would suggest looking at itunes and winamp for the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think both make sense. Depends on what the user want to do at the moment. The first option would focus the user who wants to listen an specific song. You could also allow the user to add the song to the queue, without the need to create a playlist. I find it very useful.

The second option Would be more to manage an already created playlist. Another useful feature you could add here is allowing the user to add multiple songs at a time.